# How to find the location of a certain row in another Dataframe

Tags: pandas

Assume I have two dataframe with same structure, and I know row 1 in the dfA is also in dfB.

I am wondering how to find the location of row 1 in dfB.

[Image dfA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av87r.png)

For example, I have a dfA as shown in the graph. If I know there exist a same row3 in dfB. How can I find the location of row3 (age: 53, workclass: Private) in dfB. ( dfA and dfB both has around 40000 rows, and has same number of features.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your sample dataframes.

Comment: i think this post [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) could help

Comment: @user3483203 Hi, I've add a simple sample dataframe.

Comment: Do not post dataframes as images, post them as *test* in your question

Answer (score 0):

To get only one row that particular row must be unique or else you'll get more than one rows.

```
dfB[['age', 'workclass']][(dfA.age == 53) & (dfA.workclass == "Private")]
```

If you want all columns of the dfB dataframe just remove the [['age', 'workclass']] and you will get all the rows in dfB dataframe where age = 53 and workclass = "Private".

To get the index values of the rows in the second dataframe just add .index at the end.

```
dfB[['age', 'workclass']][(dfA.age == 53) & (dfA.workclass == "Private")].index
```

Comment: Thank you Kranthi. Is there a faster way, each row actually has 14 features...I just want to get the location of the same row in the second dataframe.

Comment: I dont think there is a faster way than this. And btw by location you meant index in the second dataframe? If you meant that I've updated my answer. Please dont hesitate to upvote! :) @ShihaoWen